# Ruby on Rails Query Help

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have the following query

```
User.sum(:experience, :group => "clan", :conditions => ["created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", "2010-02-15", "2010-02-16"])
```

I want to return the top 50 clans in terms of experience listed from most experience to least experience with only the top 50 in experience returning.  How would I modify the query to achieve that result.  I know I'll need :limit => 50 to limit the query but if I add :order => "clan DESC" I get the error column "users.experience" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Based on that ActiveRecord query, it seems like you are aggregating users to find the total experience of each clan ordered by most experienced to least. Is that correct?

It might be helpful to state exactly what you mean by 'results' - if you want users the sum method is not what you want.

Comment: tomtoday - that's correct and I've updated the original question to reflect this.  What should I use to replace .sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the calculation in the order clause

```
User.sum(:experience, :group => "clan", :order=> "sum(experience) DESC", :limit => 50, :conditions => ["created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", "2010-02-15", "2010-02-16"])
```

Comment: Does this not work??  I'm trying to make sure I don't have a mistake in my logic...